# AWS Android SDK connection timeouts and retries

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-external-storage

I have been using the AWS android sdk(s) to deal with files on S3 inside my android application. There were some issues that were being faced by the users and few of these are related to connection timeouts. While setting up the `AmazonS3`client in my application, I have set the timeout and the retries using the following code:

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfiguration.setMaxErrorRetry(4);
clientConfiguration.setConnectionTimeout(10000); // default is 10 secs
clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(15000); // default is 50 secs
```

Everywhere I read, it says that the `maxErrorRetry`only does retries for `failed retryable requests`. Do the errors related to the connection timeout and socket connection timeout also come under this category? If not, what is the solution for this case? I have been searching for this for quite some time now but did not get any clear answer on this.

Also, I have been facing two specific exceptions which I get in my `TransferListener` callback. There are:

1. Unable to store object contents to disk: Read time out (14% of all the users who face any AWS exception face this exception)
2. Unable to store object contents to disk: timeout (17.4% of all the users who face any AWS exception face this exception)

The above two are the most painful for us. I have been assuming that these occur because of there is no more storage left on the user device. I have been using the application specific directory in the external storage to store the files and now thinking to move these to the cache so that the system handles the cleaning of files if there is no more space left on the device. Do you think this is a good solution assuming that the problem is running out of space on the user device.
What are the other possibilities because of which the above mentioned storage related exceptions can occur?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs at three places in the SDK, out of which two places are significant and applicable here.

(1) https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/0958a37b4757c41cac40597b973ff417e0b758c4/aws-android-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/internal/ServiceUtils.java#L284

(2) https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/3983fda8c2d8703399ac4e9bf6ec0464d000a5af/aws-android-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/s3/transferutility/DownloadTask.java#L161

I suspect that it is in the (2) which is throwing the exception in your case. This can occur for multiple reasons and storage not available is just one of them.

(1) The S3 object does not exist or the S3 bucket/object does not have the required permissions. Please check on AWS S3 Console if you have the required permissions for your users to access content.
(2) There might be a network interruption during the download. Check if there is proper network throughout the transfer

Check AWS CloudWatch Logs to see if there are any failures in the logs.

Comment: thank you for you reply. The S3 bucket object does have the required permissions. The app is in production and these are the exceptions occurring to a small percentage of the users. Other aspects, I will surely look into.

Comment: If the issue still persists, can you create a Forum Post / GitHub Issue with stack trace and more details on reproducing the issue?